# SharePoint GetGroupCollectionFromUser Web Service Returns `HTTP request was forbidden` error

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, sharepoint-2007, console-application, wss

I want to get the list of all groups that a user belongs to in SharePoint using a console application. I'm new to SharePoint dev, so here is my admittedly amateurish attempt.

```
    private static string GetUserGroupCollection(string LoginName)
    {

        UserGroupSoapClient ug = new UserGroupSoapClient();
        ug.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "myusername";
        ug.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "mypassword";
        return ( ug.GetGroupCollectionFromUser(LoginName)).ToString();
    }
```

I have included a "Service Reference" to my SP web service available at  `http://server02/aaa/DOCS/_vti_bin/usergroup.asmx`

When I try the code above I get `The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.`

Can you please show me a basic example of how this can be done?  Please note that I do not want to make the reference as "Web Reference". Thank you.

Comment: Could you please share your app.config? I think the problem is in security config of httpBinding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your SharePoint WebServices web application use NTLM authentication you can try this

```
ug.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential("myusername", "mypassword");
```

and in your `app.config`

```
<security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
</security>
```

Edited:

Because NTLM authentication is disabled in you web application for access to web services you must first login with Authentication.asmx web service and retrieve the authentication cookie and send it with other web services calls like this:

```
            string cookie = "";
        LoginResult loginResult;
        string result;

        AuthenticationSoapClient authentication = new AuthenticationSoapClient();
        UserGroupSoapClient ug = new UserGroupSoapClient();

        using(OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(authentication.InnerChannel))
        {
            loginResult = authentication.Login("user", "pass");
            if (loginResult.ErrorCode == LoginErrorCode.NoError)
            {
                MessageProperties props = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties;
                HttpResponseMessageProperty prop = props[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name] as HttpResponseMessageProperty;
                string cookies = prop.Headers["Set-Cookie"];
                // You must search cookies to find cookie named loginResult.CookieName and set its value to cookie variable;
                cookie = cookies.Split(';').SingleOrDefault(c => c.StartsWith(loginResult.CookieName));
            }
        }

        HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
        httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add(System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, cookie);
        using (new OperationContextScope(ug.InnerChannel))
        {
            OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, httpRequestProperty);
            result = ug.GetGroupCollectionFromUser(LoginName).ToString();
        }
```

and make sure in app.config allowCookies properties of all binding be false.

```
<basicHttpBinding>
   <binding name="AuthenticationSoap" allowCookies="false"/>
   <binding name="UserGroupSoap" allowCookies="false"/>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Comment: Thanks @Kambiz The Sharepoint Site uses Forms Authentication; I can see the `Url` property and other properties of the Authentication Proxy object if I use "Web Reference"; I can't see those with "Service Reference". This seems to be my main problem.

Comment: @FMFF I mean SharePoint web services web application in IIS not the SharePoint Sites, you can check it in IIS Manager.BTW could you try my answer please and let me know the result.

Comment: We have NTLM disabled, Anonymous access enabled. I tried your suggestion and got `The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https'. Parameter name: via`

Comment: Is there any way I can assign you the bounty I put on this question? :-) It worked. Where can I learn about cookie handling and authentication with WCF like you demonstrated?

Comment: I don't know a source for both cookie or more general, HTTP request and response context and WCF, but you can find valuable content on http://www.pluralsight.com/training. About bounty you can find "start bounty" link bellow the comment area of your question.

Comment: Not complaining, but just curious, this works even when I don't specify `allowCookies=false` ; why is this?

Comment: `allowCookies` default value is false, but if you set to true, the solution will not work any more and this is because BasicHttpBinding will handle cookie itself. It's mean you cannot set it manually any more.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should work: (Taken / Edited from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/b17ae5c8-f845-4cee-8298-c4f7b5c52b57)

I think you should use SPGroup to get all the groups from site and find the user in all groups:

For single user and if you know the group name then you can try with this code:

```
SPWeb site = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPGroup groupToQuery = site.Groups["Project"];
bool istrue = site.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(groupToQuery);
```

If you don't know the group name then try with below code (This is not tested by me)

```
using (SPWeb rootWeb = topLevelSite.OpenWeb())
{
    foreach (SPGroup group in rootWeb.Groups)
    {
        bool isUserInGroup = IsUserInGroup(group, currentUser.LoginName);
    }
}

private Boolean IsUserInGroup(SPGroup group, string userLoginName)
{
    bool userIsInGroup = false;

    try
    {
        SPUser x = group.Users[userLoginName];
        userIsInGroup = true;
    }
    catch (SPException)
    {
        userIsInGroup = false;
    }

    return userIsInGroup;
}
```

Comment: this code use SharePoint object model and just work on the server, FMFF wants access SharePoint through WebService which does not need to run on the SharePoint server.